# The type placeholder `_` is not allowed within types on item signatures

Tags: vector, rust, placeholder

Beginner question; and a search couldn't find anything similar.

**Background:** I'm just practising functions in Rust by making a shuffling function. Program takes in any arguments and shuffles them and stores them in '`result`'

**Question:** I guess I can't use `V<_>` in a function header so what would I use in this situation?

**MCVE:**

```
use std::io;
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::env;

fn main()
{
    let mut result = shuffle(env::args().collect());
}//End of main

fn shuffle(args: Vec<_>) -> Vec<_>
{ 
    let mut temp = Vec::with_capacity((args.capacity()));
    while args.len() > 1 
    {
        //LET N REPRESENT A RANDOM NUMBER GENERATED ON EACH ITERATION
        let mut n = 2;
        temp.push(args.swap_remove(n));
    }
    return temp;
}//End of shuffle function
```

**[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=60c252f7a696d68e679c&version=stable)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would convert your function to a generic function:

```
fn shuffle<T>(args: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
```

See it in the playpen: http://is.gd/MCCxal

Comment: Ohh okay thank you! I attempted replacing _ with a T but i didn't realize i needed to also add <T> after the function name. 

In which situations is the type required to be put after the function name?

Comment: It is always required if you don't have concrete type like `i32` or `A` where `A` is a struct you defined. In case the function is a method, you also can use generic arguments to the type.